# How to detect hidden rows in excel document using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is possible to detect when a row is hidden in an EXCEL (*.xlsx) document reads with **Openpyxl**?

```
...
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb_obj.get_sheet_by_name(page)

for row_num in range(first_row, ws.max_row + 1):
    # Need to check here if a row is hidden (ex: its height is 0)
    # ws.row_dimensions[row_num].height -> Is always None (Not useful to me)
...
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible but you should first check whether the row is in the collection.

Comment: I have not understood you. Can you give an example or explain it a little more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer I was looking for:

> worksheet.row_dimensions[row_number].hidden

```
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb_obj.get_sheet_by_name(page)

for row_num in range(first_row, ws.max_row + 1):
     # is this row hidden?
     if row_num in wx.row_dimensions and ws.row_dimensions[row_num].hidden:
         print('The row {} is hidden'.format(row_num))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful

Comment: This is the wrong solution. The row_dimensions collection doesn't need to hold the entire range. The code will generate an error on line: if ws.row_dimensions[row_num].hidden:

Comment: You need to check the condition: row_num in ws.row_dimensions.keys().

Comment: Adding fix suggested by @stansy (Thanks).